# Passing around partially complete builder instances

Tags: design-patterns, builder

Is it acceptable to pass builder instances around from one object to another to add the different field values?

In the below example, the details to create the VacationPlan instance should be obtained from multiple places (DateAdder and PlaceAdder). The Organizer creates the builder instance and passes that as arguments to these "appender" instances and finally executes the build() call.

Example:

```
public class Organizer {

        private final DateAdder dateAdder;
        private final PlaceAdder placeAdder;
        private final VacationProviderSearch vacationProviderSearch;

        public void organizeVacation() {
            VacationPlan.Builder vacationPlanBuilder = VacationPlan.newBuilder();
            vacationPlanBuilder = dateAdder.addDate(vacationPlanBuilder);
            vacationPlanBuilder = placeAdder.addPlace(vacationPlanBuilder);
            VacationPlan vacationPlan = vacationPlanBuilder.build();
            List<Provider> providers = vacationProviderSearch.getProviders(vacationPlan);
            // use providers to get the best vacation provider
        }

    }
```

---

We were discussing this approach at work and I argued it is better for those individual appenders to accept non-builder instance as arguments and return their respective output as POJOs.

Something like below:

```
public void organizeVacation() {
    VacationDateRange dateRange = dateProvider.getDateRange(userRequestJson);
    String location = locationProvider.getLocation(userRequestJson);
    VacationPlan vacationPlan = vacationPlanBuilder.newBuilder()
            .startDate(dateRange.getStartDate())
            .endDate(dateRange.getEndDate())
            .location(location)
            .build();
    List<Provider> providers = vacationProviderSearch.getProviders(vacationPlan);
    // use providers to get the best vacation provider
}
```

This makes sure there are no mutable instances floating around the system. Which of these approaches is better?

Answer (score 2):

The second approach is cleaner since it eliminates unnecessary coupling of the date/location providers to the builder or the VacationPlan type. It also makes it easier to unit test the providers (testing in the first approach would require exposing getters on the builder or mocking the builder, neither of which is preferable).

Comment: Thanks! I am also curious if there's a general consensus about the correctness of passing around partially complete builders across different objects to complete it. To me, it seems like a code smell irrespective of the situation.

Comment: In general, I would avoid passing around builders but general statements will always have exceptions. When something "seems" like a code smell, it helps to think about why. Does it violate design principles such as SOLID? Is it harder to test or maintain?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add a Adder interface first which will be implemented by `DateAdder` and `PlaceAdder`. This Adder interface can have one method named as `getData()`.

Create a List of Adder object in the Organizer either by passing it to using constructor or some other way.

Create a method in `VacationPlan.Builder` named as `withAdder()` which will take the Adder as an argument and read its data to update builder object.

Inside `organizeVacation()` method, iterate over Adder list and call `withAdder()` method of `VacationPlan.Builder` by passing Adder to this method. Inside `withAdder()` method you can call method of `Adder` interface to get the Adder specific data.

Please do let me know in case you need further clarification or if I am not making any sense.